# Greedy match using regex in VBA for Excel

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Let me put the question in a precise way
How to split based on pattern in vba

`<cr>1st data<rc>2nd data<ab>3rd data<ba>4th data`

i use the following way to split it in perl

`my @values = split(/<([\w]+)>/,$string);`

and it gives me output as

`cr 1st data rc 2nd data ab 3rd data ba 4th data`

i want to do the same with vba split function what should be my approach

Comment: Take a look at the `Split` function.

Comment: Hi
sorry for the problem 
The string will be like `<cr>first data1<rc>second data2<ab>third data3<ba>Fourth data4`

Comment: hi 
i looked at it but i was not able to understand anything properly since i donot know vb at all
i have already done this with perl script but i have no idea how to do with vba
so if you can provide an example it will be really helpful

Comment: If you can give me a sample example for split function this will help a lot

Comment: It's exactly the same as [in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) (2nd overload).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "code for me" or a "teach me to code" site.  If you have code that is not working please put it in the original post using edit, with specific direction as to the problem with the code and we will help overcome that specific problem.

Comment: @ScottCraner i understand the issue but all i want is just an example however i have tried some thing which i will post

Comment: @ScottCraner please try to understand i donot want to learn VB if you can give me an example or redirect me where this is explained that will be helpful

Comment: @ScottCraner i already know the split function i want to know how to add regex to it
this thing is pretty easy in perl but i am struggling in VBa

Comment: Copying and posting code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops is not the same as posting your code.  What have you tried to modify the code to do what you want?  It is expected that the poster will do some homework on their own.  This is not the site for what you want.  We are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: hi 
why you guys are not understanding i have no issue with split function i want to know how to put regex into it so that it splits based on pattern

Comment: @RajatBatra - Because I'd argue that `Split` is the better solution to your problem than using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code for Split:

```
Sub splitandUbound()


Dim s() As String, s1 As String
Dim i As Integer

s1 = "C:\_KTemp\TEMP\Test Macro for FolderExists\test\test1\test2\test3"

' Create the array
s = Split(s1, "\")

' show results of the array
For i = 0 To UBound(s)
    debug.print s(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @kerry
the problem is my data is some what like `<cr>first data1<rc>second data2<ab>third data3<ba>Fourth data4` and i want to split based on tag and want out put as 
first data 1 second data2 third data3 fourth data 4 for which i need to put regex in split and i am struggling with that and need help with that 
in perl this is very straight forward
i am not at all a vb expert or even beginner

Comment: Ah!  It sounds like you may need a formula using "Mid" ... Example:  I put your data in `A1` and in `B1` I put this formula:  `=MID(A1,FIND("<cr>",A1,1)+4,FIND("<rc>",A1,1)-5)`  This gave me what was between `<cr>` and `<rc>`.  You'd just need to do the next part of the formula in `C1` something like:  `=MID(A1,FIND("<rc>",A1,1)+4,FIND("<ab>",A1,1)-5)`  and so on...

Comment: sorry i may sound a lot amateur but what are A1 B1 C1 
can you explain a little

Comment: Oh i got it a1 b1 c1 are row columns of excel
but when i try the formula suggested by you i get #value error

Comment: Thanks a lot kerry it worked 
you were really really helpful

Comment: I appreciate a lot what you all guys do for everyone